# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createMessageComponentCollector')

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Im trying to fix this error that I keep getting when I run `/help`, and don't know what I did wrong, I tried to do what I could with the error, but im getting annoyed at this point.

My error:

```
/app/slashCommands/Miscellaneous/help.js:138
   const collector = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, componentType: "SELECT_MENU" });
                         ^
  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createMessageComponentCollector')
```

Code:

```
const { MessageEmbed, Message, Client } = require("discord.js");
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
const client = require("../../index");
const config = require("../../botconfig");
const create_menu = require("../../models/helpMenu.js");
const prefixSchema = require("../../models/prefix");

module.exports = {
  name: "help",
  description: "Displays all available command categories!",
  aliases: ["h"],
  usage: "<command> or <category>",
  run: async (client, interaction, args, db) => {
    const data = await prefixSchema.findOne({ Guild: interaction.guild.id });

    if (data) {
      let categories = [];
      let cots = [];

      if (!args[0]) {
        let ignored = ["Giveaway", "Owner"];

        const emoji = {
          Action: "",
          Admin: "",
          Birthday: "",
          Economy: "",
          Fun: "",
          Giveaway: "",
          Image: "️",
          Minigame: "",
          Miscellaneous: "⚙️",
          Moderation: "️",
          Owner: "",
          Ticket: "",
        };

        let cmdCategory = [];

        readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
          if (ignored.includes(dir)) return;
          const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

          if (ignored.includes(dir)) return;

          const name = `${emoji[dir]} - ${dir}`;

          let categoryName = dir;

          let categoryDir = new Object();

          categoryDir = {
            name: name,
            value: "​",
            inline: true,
          };

          categories.push(categoryDir);
          cmdCategory.push(categoryName);
        });

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle("__Crimson's Help Menu__")
          .setDescription(`>>> Default Prefix: \`${config.defaultPrefix}\`\nServer Prefix: \`${data.Prefix}\``)
          .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .addFields(categories)
          .setColor("#EE1C25")
          .setFooter("Navigate through the embeds using the provided menu below", interaction.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .setTimestamp();

        let menus = create_menu(cmdCategory);
        return interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: menus.smenu, allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } }).then((msg) => {
            const menuID = menus.sid;

            const select = async (interaction) => {
              if (interaction.customId != menuID) return;

              let { values } = interaction;

              let value = values[0];

              let commands2 = [];

              readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
                if (dir.toLowerCase() !== value.toLowerCase()) return;
                const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

                const cmds = commands.map((command) => {
                  let file = require(`../../commands/${dir}/${command}`);

                  if (!file.name) return "No command name.";

                  let name = file.name.replace(".js", "");

                  if (client.commands.get(name).hidden) return;

                  let emoji = client.commands.get(name).emoji;
                  let emoji2 = emoji ? `${emoji} ` : "• ";

                  let obj = { cname: `${emoji2}\`${name}\`` };

                  return obj;
                });

                let dota = new Object();

                cmds.map((co) => {
                  if (co == undefined) return;

                  dota = {
                    name: `${cmds.length === 0 ? "Processing..." : co.cname}`,
                    value: "​",
                    inline: true,
                  };
                  commands2.push(dota);
                });

                cots.push(dir.toLowerCase());
              });

              if (cots.includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
                const cmdEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                  .setTitle(`__${value.charAt(0) + value.slice(1)} Commands__`)
                  .addFields(commands2)
                  .setColor("#EE1C25");

                await interaction.deferUpdate();

                return interaction.editReply({ embeds: [cmdEmbed], components: menus.smenu, allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
              }
            };

            const filter = (interaction) => {
              if (interaction.user.id === interaction.user.id) return true;
              return interaction.reply({ content: "<:CL_VoteCross:781265541804720148> You cannot use this menu.", ephemeral: true });
            };

            const collector = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, componentType: "SELECT_MENU" });
            collector.on("collect", select);
            collector.on("end", () => null);
          });
      } else {
        let commands2 = [];

        readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
          if (dir.toLowerCase() !== args[0].toLowerCase()) return;
          const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

          const cmds = commands.map((command) => {
            let file = require(`../../commands/${dir}/${command}`);

            if (!file.name) return "Unable to find requested command";

            let name = file.name.replace(".js", "");

            if (client.commands.get(name).hidden) return;

            let emoji = client.commands.get(name).emoji;
            let emoji2 = emoji ? `${emoji} ` : "";

            let obj = { cname: `${emoji2}\`${name}\`` };

            return obj;
          });

          let dota = new Object();

          cmds.map((co) => {
            if (co == undefined) return;

            dota = {
              name: `${cmds.length === 0 ? "In progress..." : "• " + co.cname}`,
              value: "​",
              inline: true,
            };
            commands2.push(dota);
          });

          cots.push(dir.toLowerCase());
        });

        const command = client.commands.get(args[0].toLowerCase()) || client.commands.find((c) => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(args[0].toLowerCase()));

        if (cots.includes(args[0].toLowerCase())) {
          const cmdEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`__${args[0].charAt(0) + args[0].slice(1)} commands__`)
            .addFields(commands2)
            .setColor("#EE1C25");
          return interaction.reply({ embeds: [cmdEmbed], allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
        }

        if (!command) {
          const noCmdEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Unknown Command/Category")
            .setDescription(`The command or category you are trying to find is not in our database, if you think this is a mistake.. please let us know!\n\n\n**Options**\n\`\`\`${config.defaultPrefix}help <category name>\`\`\` \`\`\`${config.defaultPrefix}help <command name>\`\`\``)
            .setFooter(`Command Requested by ${interaction.user.tag}`, interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .setTimestamp()
            .setColor("#EE1C25");
          return await interaction.reply({ embeds: [noCmdEmbed], allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
        }

        const cmdDetailsEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .setDescription(`**Command:** \`${command.name}\``)
          .addFields(
            {
              name: "Usage",
              value: command.usage
                ? `\`\`\`${config.defaultPrefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\`\`\``
                : "`No usage for this command`",
            },
            {
              name: "Description",
              value: command.description
                ? `\`\`\`${command.description}\`\`\``
                : "`No description for this command`",
            },
            {
              name: "Aliases",
              value: command.aliases
                ? `\`\`\`${command.aliases.join(", ")}\`\`\``
                : "`No aliases for this command`",
            }
          )
          .setFooter(`Command Requested by ${interaction.user.tag}`, interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
          .setTimestamp()
          .setColor("#EE1C25");
        return await interaction.reply({ embeds: [cmdDetailsEmbed], allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
      }
    } else if (!data) {
      let categories = [];
      let cots = [];

      if (!args[0]) {
        let ignored = ["Giveaway", "Owner"];

        const emoji = {
          Action: "",
          Admin: "",
          Birthday: "",
          Economy: "",
          Fun: "",
          Giveaway: "",
          Image: "️",
          Minigame: "",
          Miscellaneous: "⚙️",
          Moderation: "️",
          Owner: "",
          Ticket: "",
        };

        let cmdCategory = [];

        readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
          if (ignored.includes(dir)) return;
          const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

          if (ignored.includes(dir)) return;

          const name = `${emoji[dir]} - ${dir}`;

          let categoryName = dir;

          let categoryDir = new Object();

          categoryDir = {
            name: name,
            value: "​",
            inline: true,
          };

          categories.push(categoryDir);
          cmdCategory.push(categoryName);
        });

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle("__Crimson's Help Menu__")
          .setDescription(`>>> Default Prefix: \`${config.defaultPrefix}\`\nServer Prefix: \`none\``)
          .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .addFields(categories)
          .setColor("#EE1C25")
          .setFooter("Navigate through the embeds using the provided menu below", interaction.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .setTimestamp();

        let menus = create_menu(cmdCategory);
        return interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: menus.smenu, allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } }).then((msg) => {
            const menuID = menus.sid;

            const select = async (interaction) => {
              if (interaction.customId != menuID) return;

              let { values } = interaction;

              let value = values[0];

              let commands2 = [];

              readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
                if (dir.toLowerCase() !== value.toLowerCase()) return;
                const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

                const cmds = commands.map((command) => {
                  let file = require(`../../commands/${dir}/${command}`);

                  if (!file.name) return "No command name.";

                  let name = file.name.replace(".js", "");

                  if (client.commands.get(name).hidden) return;

                  let emoji = client.commands.get(name).emoji;
                  let emoji2 = emoji ? `${emoji} ` : "• ";

                  let obj = { cname: `${emoji2}\`${name}\`` };

                  return obj;
                });

                let dota = new Object();

                cmds.map((co) => {
                  if (co == undefined) return;

                  dota = {
                    name: `${cmds.length === 0 ? "Processing..." : co.cname}`,
                    value: "​",
                    inline: true,
                  };
                  commands2.push(dota);
                });

                cots.push(dir.toLowerCase());
              });

              if (cots.includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
                const cmdEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                  .setTitle(`__${value.charAt(0) + value.slice(1)} Commands__`)
                  .addFields(commands2)
                  .setColor("#EE1C25");

                await interaction.deferUpdate();

                return interaction.editReply({ embeds: [cmdEmbed], components: menus.smenu, allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
              }
            };

            const filter = (interaction) => {
              if (interaction.user.id === interaction.user.id) return true;
              return interaction.reply({ content: "<:CL_VoteCross:781265541804720148> You cannot use this menu.", ephemeral: true });
            };

            const collector = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, componentType: "SELECT_MENU" });
            collector.on("collect", select);
            collector.on("end", () => null);
          });
      } else {
        let commands2 = [];

        readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
          if (dir.toLowerCase() !== args[0].toLowerCase()) return;
          const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

          const cmds = commands.map((command) => {
            let file = require(`../../commands/${dir}/${command}`);

            if (!file.name) return "Unable to find requested command";

            let name = file.name.replace(".js", "");

            if (client.commands.get(name).hidden) return;

            let emoji = client.commands.get(name).emoji;
            let emoji2 = emoji ? `${emoji} ` : "";

            let obj = { cname: `${emoji2}\`${name}\`` };

            return obj;
          });

          let dota = new Object();

          cmds.map((co) => {
            if (co == undefined) return;

            dota = {
              name: `${cmds.length === 0 ? "In progress..." : "• " + co.cname}`,
              value: "​",
              inline: true,
            };
            commands2.push(dota);
          });

          cots.push(dir.toLowerCase());
        });

        const command = client.commands.get(args[0].toLowerCase()) || client.commands.find((c) => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(args[0].toLowerCase()));

        if (cots.includes(args[0].toLowerCase())) {
          const cmdEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`__${args[0].charAt(0) + args[0].slice(1)} commands__`)
            .addFields(commands2)
            .setColor("#EE1C25");
          return interaction.reply({ embeds: [cmdEmbed], allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
        }

        if (!command) {
          const noCmdEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Unknown Command/Category")
            .setDescription(`The command or category you are trying to find is not in our database, if you think this is a mistake.. please let us know!\n\n\n**Options**\n\`\`\`${config.defaultPrefix}help <category name>\`\`\` \`\`\`${config.defaultPrefix}help <command name>\`\`\``)
            .setFooter(`Command Requested by ${interaction.user.tag}`, interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .setTimestamp()
            .setColor("#EE1C25");
          return await interaction.reply({ embeds: [noCmdEmbed], allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
        }

        const cmdDetailsEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .setDescription(`**Command:** \`${command.name}\``)
          .addFields(
            {
              name: "Usage",
              value: command.usage
                ? `\`\`\`${config.defaultPrefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\`\`\``
                : "`No usage for this command`",
            },
            {
              name: "Description",
              value: command.description
                ? `\`\`\`${command.description}\`\`\``
                : "`No description for this command`",
            },
            {
              name: "Aliases",
              value: command.aliases
                ? `\`\`\`${command.aliases.join(", ")}\`\`\``
                : "`No aliases for this command`",
            })
          .setFooter(`Command Requested by ${interaction.user.tag}`, interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
          .setTimestamp()
          .setColor("#EE1C25");
        return await interaction.reply({ embeds: [cmdDetailsEmbed], allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
      }
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Can you show your code since the error by itself will not help that much

Comment: yep, sorry about that. It updated with the error and the code.

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing your code there's not much we can help you with, but from the error I would assume that `msg` is undefined.
Try logging `msg` before creating the collector, if it returns undefined, there's your problem.